# Converting an expression to binary tree

Tags: data-structures

How do I convert the following expression to a binary tree?

`((A + B)/(C * D + E)*(F - G))`

Comment: Not sure if this question is suitable here, This is called [expression tree](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c9/s4.html)

Comment: @PhamTrung, I think it is not suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to order of operations, what is the last operation? It will be the multiplication `*` between `(A+B)/(C*D+E)` on the one hand and `(F-G)` on the other. So the root node of your tree will have the operation `*`, while the left branch will have `(A+B)/(C*D+E)` and the right branch will have `(F-G)`. Ask the same question on  each of those branches, etc., until you reach the leaves of the tree which will be letters `A`, ..., `G`.